# Binary search start or end is target

Tags: binary-search

Why is it that when I see example code for binary search there is never an if statement to check if the start of the array or end is the target?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {

    public static int binary_search(int[] arr, int left, int right, int target) {
        if (left > right) {
            return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (target == arr[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }

        if (target < arr[mid]) {
            return binary_search(arr, left, mid - 1, target);
        }

        return binary_search(arr, mid + 1, right, target);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 3, 2, 4, -1, 0, 1, 10, 20, 9, 7 };

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Index: " + i + " value: " + arr[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(binary_search(arr, arr[0], arr.length - 1, -1));
    }
}
```

in this example if the target was -1 or 20 the search would enter recursion. But it added an if statement to check if target is mid, so why not add two more statements also checking if its left or right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, I may have misinterpreted the initial question. The answer below assumes that OP meant having the start/end checks as part of *each step* of the recursion, as opposed to checking *once* before the recursion even starts.

Since I don't know for sure which interpretation was intended, I'm leaving this post here for now.

---

Original post:

You seem to be under the impression that "they added an extra check for mid, so surely they should also add an extra check for start and end".

The check "Is mid the target?" is in fact not a mere optimization they added. Recursively checking "mid" is *the whole point* of a binary search.

When you have a sorted array of elements, a binary search works like this:

1. Compare the middle element to the target

   1. If the middle element is smaller, throw away the first half
   2. If the middle element is larger, throw away the second half
   3. Otherwise, we found it!
2. Repeat until we either find the target or there are no more elements.

The act of checking the middle is fundamental to determining which half of the array to continue searching through.

Now, let's say we also add a check for start and end. What does this gain us? Well, if at any point the target happens to be at the very start or end of a segment, we skip a few steps and end slightly sooner. Is this a likely event?

For small toy examples with a few elements, yeah, maybe.

For a massive real-world dataset with billions of entries? Hm, let's think about it. For the sake of simplicity, we assume that we know the target is in the array.

We start with the whole array. Is the first element the target? The odds of that is one in a billion. Pretty unlikely. Is the last element the target? The odds of that is also one in a billion. Pretty unlikely too. You've wasted two extra comparisons to speed up an extremely unlikely case.

We limit ourselves to, say, the first half. We do the same thing again. Is the first element the target? Probably not since the odds are one in half a billion.

...and so on.

The bigger the dataset, the more useless the start/end "optimization" becomes. In fact, in terms of (maximally optimized) comparisons, each step of the algorithm has three comparisons instead of the usual one. VERY roughly estimated, that suggests that the algorithm on average becomes three times slower.

Even for smaller datasets, it is of dubious use since it basically becomes a quasi-linear search instead of a binary search. Yes, the odds are higher, but on average, we can expect a larger amount of comparisons before we reach our target.

The whole point of a binary search is to reach the target with as few wasted comparisons as possible. Adding more unlikely-to-succeed comparisons is typically not the way to improve that.

Edit:

The implementation as posted by OP may also confuse the issue slightly. The implementation chooses to make *two* comparisons between target and mid. A more optimal implementation would instead make a single three-way comparison (i.e. determine ">", "=" or "<" as a single step instead of two separate ones). This is, for instance, how Java's `compareTo` or C++'s `<=>` normally works.

Comment: the OP was suggesting adding the starting index and ending index checks BEFORE entering the recursive function, therefore that would NOT increase the overall time complexity by a factor of 3. It would not affect the time complexity at all since it would only *ADD* a constant of '2' to the overall complexity.

Comment: @OkeUwechue Hm. Upon rereading the question, I agree that I may have misinterpreted it. If the checks happen _outside_ the recursive function, it would indeed be a negligible addition to the runtime while providing a nice and simple fail-fast check for values less than the first or greater than the last element.

Answer (score 1):

BambooleanLogic's answer is correct and comprehensive. I was curious about how much slower this 'optimization' made binary search, so I wrote a short script to test the change in how many comparisons are performed on average:

```
Given an array of integers 0, ... , N 
do a binary search for every integer in the array,
and count the total number of array accesses made.
```

To be fair to the optimization, I made it so that after checking `arr[left]` against target, we increase left by 1, and similarly for right, so that every comparison is as useful as possible. You can try this yourself [at Try it online](https://tio.run/##zVPLbtswELzrKxbpQVIc16LcXoQwh/xAgfboGAQbUTYBizIoBkhi@NudXdIP2YqRGEiB8kJyOTO7O1otX9y8MePNplQV/NVG2hfRKmkf56J10pTSlom09gYWqnI3YPVsjpuTdqZwf2zqJc/SIgJcuvIguAuoEKRllXuyBoYs8qFal8AhIezAI9PRKPcvJCetbhvTTug8hQEHthMPSYFzwIImqDLtpcDgCfr2PPjjbpE2ZLtu0@iTXGQN2IlVaRRFfYcpi/C4jzxmF3p8iZMk2HeHoj7m83XZX16AV@pX4MPBdDrB8NIa/s9Be/@jf3bUTtnnhg0LE8LIWglBjcRC1FIbIeIieNPqV4XmsMzfqsaCAI2eSzNTyc/00EPHKsRPsilcQx5F@3esAuML3bokkEk5TffvJP18kPavB3Va5/8lvjeIZ9se@UIZekoPbvFnavifFXTs@AUl7eS@4ZdsnxYuw7Ji73sMA2idDbk700IoRqg/WxP2yO7AZtNTTk6cX0unaxQs4V0W67HGxPotnW4Co4pXx4TRcdbi@49qHXecXlptXFJd3Xu/IPgFjQnD9eBgRYcC7li2LmC17Q/vebbeXfPj6zhcrzr2ebFrGtXN5g0)

Results:

```
Binary search on size         10:   Standard         29  Optimized         43   Ratio  1.4828
Binary search on size        100:   Standard        580  Optimized       1180   Ratio  2.0345
Binary search on size       1000:   Standard       8987  Optimized      21247   Ratio  2.3642
Binary search on size      10000:   Standard     123631  Optimized     311205   Ratio  2.5172
Binary search on size     100000:   Standard    1568946  Optimized    4108630   Ratio  2.6187
Binary search on size    1000000:   Standard   18951445  Optimized   51068017   Ratio  2.6947
Binary search on size   10000000:   Standard  223222809  Optimized  610154319   Ratio  2.7334
```

so the total comparisons does seem to tend to triple the standard number, implying the optimization becomes increasingly unhelpful for larger arrays. I'd be curious whether the limiting ratio is exactly 3.

Comment: Nice to see some concrete numbers to illustrate my otherwise purely theoretical argument. :) But yes, I posit that the ratio is always strictly less than, but asymptotically approaching, exactly three.

Unless there's some detail I can't think of, the number of comparisons should never reach exactly three times more as the "optimization" does indeed create a miniscule statistical decrease of the search depth, i.e. the few "lucky cases" that ends the search at a "premature" depth. As N grows, the significance of this "luck" shrinks, but doesn't completely vanish.

Comment: the checks for starting index and ending index were to be added in function 'main'  BEFORE the recursive call, not WITHIN the recursive call. These extra checks would therefore not affect the time complexity at all as the array size grows.

Answer (score 0):

To add some extra check for **start** and **end** along with the **mid** value is not impressive.

In any **algorithm design** the main concerned is moving around it's **complexity** either it is **time complexity** or **space complexity**. Most of the time the **time complexity** is taken as *more important aspect*.

To learn more about [Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) in different use case like -

1. If Array is not containing any repeated
2. If Array has repeated element in this case -

   a) return leftmost index/value

   b) return rightmost index/value

and many more point